# onSurfaceChanged (SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) VS onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, surfaceholder

As I'm new to Live Wallpaper development, I was struggling to know the difference between **onSurfaceChanged (SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) VS onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)** in Live Wallpaper can any one differentiate between this two methods when they are called and when they are effected on the mobile screen....

Answer (score 1):

```
  onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
```

Convenience for SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceChanged(). This is called immediately after any structural changes (format or size) have been made to the surface.
but

```
 public void onVisibilityChanged (boolean visible)
```

Called to inform you of the wallpaper becoming visible or hidden. It is very important that a wallpaper only use CPU while it is visible..

i hope this is help you.

Comment: can you elaborate the explanation of onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) --->this called when surface changed.